# CSS isn't showing up in Inspect Element?

Tags: css, google-chrome, inspect-element

So this is what the CSS SHOULD look like

```
  h1{
    font-family:monospace;
}

.main{
    border: solid #000000 0.1px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

And this is what shows up in my Inspect Element in Chrome

```
element.style {
}
user agent stylesheet
html {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: show all your code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: how do i do that in a comment?

Comment: Try clearing your cache. You Can also check the "Do not cache" checkbox in the inspector under the network tab.  This will allow the pages not to be cached when the inspector is open.

Comment: What HTML element are you inspecting? Sometimes the chrome tools is bugged close it and open it again or reload the page while closed works for me

Comment: I'm inspecting the html element itself. I'm only learning this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, there may be many things that could go wrong but I think the most probable are two:

1. Your browser is loading the CSS from cache. One way to test this is to add inline css to the element. If it loads, but the changes to your css file don't then what you might check is if there are Expires headers in your .htaccess. In any case the first thing you can do to check if this is the case is to open your Chrome developer tools, go to the Network tab, check the Disable cache option and refresh the page.
2. If the problem doesn't get fixed with the previous observation you should probably check your CSS, something might be incorrectly written, in a media query that doesn't apply or maybe some semicolon got wild and hid between the lines. It happens.

Comment: I got my own CSS to work now...finally. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: What was the problem @KyleAlexanderSullivan

Comment: Did any of the answers do the trick for you? You should accept the one that worked for you to mark the question as answered @KyleAlexanderSullivan

Answer (score 0):

#### `0.1px` not gonna work (only show for firefox as firefox change it to `1px`).

Try this:

```
.main{
    border: solid #000000 1px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

Comment: That was a typo I may have missed. I'm glad you caught that.

Comment: @KyleAlexanderSullivan are you sure your css are loaded?

Comment: @KyleAlexanderSullivan also try to do a hard reload to clean the cached CSS style sheet

Comment: @KyleAlexanderSullivan in case if you not sure how to hard reload: https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.WRdX3Lzyt24

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your CSS [see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surudoiryu/nqqkashu/)

---

```
border: solid #000000 0.1px;
```

0.1px is just working, but aint 0.1px it will be set to 1px.

---

Or your CSS is unable to be found, or some other CSS is overwritting/resetting it.

Can you link the url or make a jsfiddle yourself ? So i can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:
ctrl + shift + R if your CSS properties is not or partially showing in inspect Chrome browser