# Why does external and internal CSS not work within HTML for me?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following HTML/CSS code on our company's Intranet webpage

```
<div class="hello">hello</div>

<style>
.hello {
  color: blue
}
</style>
```

After loading the HTML I get the following result in the inspector:

[image]

After inspecting the HTML code I notice that my CSS code suddenly vanishes and I have no idea why. I tried other methods e.g. importing it via stylesheet but every CSS related code vanishes.

Except for inline CSS:

When I use

```
<h1 style="color: blue;">A heading 
</h1>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
```

rhe Code works properly.

Comment: you are not inspecting the div with the class hello in your screenshot.

Comment: Yes, they are @cloned

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is the cms system stripping inline css?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius How can I check this? I

Comment: what cms system is it? Check the web - there may be info on that. From a corporate point of view maintaining a particular look/style is important so if you can add your own custom css you can potentially change the entire look so the dev / sys admin might have forbidden  inline css

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius We are using Jive. There are not css restrictions.

Comment: Please use css file and link it in your html file.

Comment: @George Tried it and it vanishes it too after saving.

Answer (score 2):

Put `<style>` inside `<Head>`

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <style>
      h1 {color:red;}
      p {color:blue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>A heading</h1>
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it's not working. The css vanishes here too.

Comment: Do you have live link for page?

Comment: No sorry, it's a company webpage only visible through vpn.

Comment: First try CTRL+ F5 and try again. Second can you see any css files links in <head>?

Comment: @ValentinFranke by "vanishes" do you mean the "browser inspector" doesn't show it? There are a number of reasons this might occur intentionally... ask your company tech admin if they've got anything that will do this. If you "View Source Code" on your HTML the style should be in there?

Comment: @Martin Not only this, but when I save the HTML and reopen it the css is gone.

Comment: Well how bizarre!

Comment: This problem can be only if you have override for page .. do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

```
 <html>
<body>

<h1>A heading</h1>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<style>
  h1 {color:red;}
  p {color:blue;}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

It's visible to me...

Look at following link

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956786/css-isnt-showing-up-in-inspect-element)
[2](https://groups.google.com/g/google-chrome-developer-tools/c/SvYDqAzkgE0?pli=1)
[3](https://legacy.forums.gravityhelp.com/topic/css-showing-in-inspect-element-but-not-in-css-file)

Comment: It does work of course but not for me and I dont know why! When I copy paste your code, save and reopen all that remains is: <h1>A heading</h1>
<p>A paragraph.</p>. When I use '<h1 style="color: blue;">A heading 
</h1>
<p>A paragraph.</p> it works'..

Comment: @ValentinFranke I have edited my question(I added some link look at them...).

Answer (score 0):

`<style></style>` tag must be included inside the `<head></head>`. Refer the MDN [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)